# What does the Mitigation stat mean in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I keep seeing it, specifically in skills that debuff it on enemies, it's never explained what it is though.

**Does anyone know what does the Mitigation stat mean in Neverwinter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mitigation in Neverwinter means exactly what the actual definition of the word means.**

So for example, Ray of Enfeeblement has the following description:

> **Ray of Enfeeblement**:    Over several seconds, deal damage to your enemy while ***decreasing*** their damage and ***Mitigation***. ***Debuff*** duration
>   increased based on stack of Arcane Mastery

SO, what this all means is for a period of time you've lowered the targets ability to reduce the damage from your incoming attacks.

Well how is the target mitigating (there's that word again) damage from your attacks in the first place? Good question, glad you asked.

Damage Resistance **IS** mitigation.

Damage Resistance decreases the amount of damage you take from incoming attacks. Defense helps to increase this stat.

[image]

Therefore, if you put this all together using what you just learned (stay with me now) it goes something like this...

"Target X" has a damage resistance stat 21.2%.

You cast Ray of Enfeeblement on Target X which reduces his damage **mitigation** by 15%.

Over the next several seconds, Target X's Damage Resistance (ie: mitigation) is effectively 6.2%

21.2% - 15% = 6.2%

Comment: So.... why not just call it... "Damage Resistance"? Also, no need to get cocky, not all of us are native English speaker and even though I consider me English to be pretty good, obscure words like "Mitigation" are still unfamiliar to me. Thanks for your answer though.

Comment: I apologize. I didn't view your profile and kotekzot's profile till after I replied, at which point I discovered you were from Israel and kotekzot was from Russia and it was at that point that I realized my reply could be taken harshly. So again, it was not personal and I apologize if I offended either of you. As to why they were not consistence in their words is anyone's guess. Mitigation is one word while "Damage Resistance" is two. Think of it like this: http://www.theologyweb.com/campus/showthread.php?108306-Hebrew-words-for-love Many Hebrew words for love, but in different contexts.

Comment: Yeah well, "Love" isn't quite the same as "Damage Resistance" :P Thanks

Comment: Personally, I think it would be clearer if they had just written "decreases both their damage and damage resistance." Unless it implies that _other_ resistances are also lowered, too. Is it "damage" and "damage mitigation" or "damage" and "all mitigation"? Ambiguous to a native English speaker, much less the other 95% of the planet.

Answer (score -1):

mit·i·ga·tion
ˌmitəˈgāSHən/
noun
noun: mitigation

```
1.
the action of reducing the severity, seriousness, or painfulness of something.
"the emphasis is on the identification and mitigation of pollution"
```